# Combine permissions of two roles to one user

Tags: sql-server, roles

I have two roles: `sales` and `marketing`
two schemas: `salesData` and `marketingData`

sales has readOnly access to salesData but no access to marketingData
marketing has readonly access to marketingData

Like this:

```
grant select on salesData to sales;
deny select on marketingData to sales;

grant select on marketingData to marketing;
```

John is the manager for both departments, so he should able to read both schemas

If I assign user John with both roles, john will have no access to marketingData as the rule with less permission will apply.

*What is the proper way to deal with such user/role **without** creating another role like 'someManager'?*

Comment: I don't understand, why you  deny  marketingData . In that default, there is no need. He does not have direct permision with marketingData to  sales.

Answer (score 0):

A deny will trump a select, so you will need another role for managers and they cant be a member of other roles where a deny is in place.
This is useful

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2894/understanding-grant-deny-and-revoke-in-sql-server/